# Why do I get a runtime error when I use realloc in an array of pointers?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, runtime-error

I am trying to use a dynamically allocated 2-dimensional array to solve a problem. I would like to have a "jagged" array with a fixed number of rows but a dynamically allocated column count for each of the rows.

(The above snippet isn't the actual code I am working on, This was just made to emphasize the issue I am facing.)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
    int stayinloop;
    int *a[10];
    do { 
       for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
           int colcount;
           scanf("%d", &colcount);
           a[i] = realloc(a[i], colcount*sizeof(int));
       }
       printf("Enter 0 for exiting now.\n");
       scanf("%d", &stayinloop)
    } while (stayinloop);
    return 0;
}
```

This code gives a runtime error on executing (the inputs I used were 1, 2, 3 ... 10). In my original code, on executing the `stderr` showed `realloc(): invalid pointer`. I do not understand why - Isn't this a valid pointer as I have not statically declared the pointer `a[i]` or does `realloc()` have any other rule regarding array of pointers, which I missed.

Comment: You do: `int *a[10];` But, the values in `a` are _uninitialized_ (i.e. random). Change to: `int *a[10] = { NULL };` and they will all be initialized to 0 (i.e. `NULL`) which is what you want

Comment: `int *a[10];` must be initialized to 0 before calling `realloc`.

Comment: use `malloc` instead `realloc`: `a[i] = malloc(colcount*sizeof(int));` - or check `if (a[i]) { a[i] = realloc(a[i], colcount*sizeof(int)); } else { a[i] = malloc(colcount*sizeof(int));}`

Comment: `realloc()` only works to alter an existing dynamically allocated array; you generally would use `calloc()` to create the initial array, and only use `realloc()` to resize an existing array.

Comment: @BitLauncher, In the snippet I have put `malloc` may be used, but for the purposes of the actual problem I am working on, I need to resize it depending on the situation, I just used this snippet to highlight the issue I am facing.

Comment: I updated the code - with the if it should work now. Your example code best represents all the cases you wish to have - like reallocating, so another loop around the for I would add.

Comment: @Schol-R-LEA if you pass `NULL` to `realloc` it works the same as `malloc` (as documented) so its use here would be valid apart from the uninitialised array. There is no need for `calloc` because OP will immediately overwrite.

Comment: @PhysicsWizardUd you'll need an array for `colcount` too, or there will be no way of knowing the length of each jag (unless you use a sentinel value).

Comment: @WeatherVane, Yes, I used that in the actual code. I just wanted this question to address only the issue I was facing - regarding the runtime error.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot this: **C is a programming language where the declaration of an array does NOT automatically initalize its values to a default value!** Depending on the runtime state/where it is placed in memory, it can contain random values!

Answer (score 0):

None of the pointers in the a[i] array have been created yet, you have just allocated space to hold 10 pointers. So rather than realloc you just need to malloc

```
a[i] = malloc(colcount*sizeof(int));
```

You could use realloc if later you wanted to increase the length of one of the rows.

Comment: Or avoid type mis-match: `a[i] = malloc(colcount * sizeof a[i][0]);`.